# Add mouse hover effects into style

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is it possible to add the mouse hover effect, changing the `background-color` of what I am hovering without putting it in the .css file? My fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yikevinqu/eeu9unhm/1/  I want to add a mouse hovering effect to change the background color of what I am hovering, and is there a way to do this in my `var contentMenuStyle = { ... }` ?

Comment: I'm pretty confused what exactly you're trying to accomplish here.  Your `contentMenuStyle` variable exists in your `ContextMenus` component, but the table cells that you would be hovering over exist inside your `Search` component, which is `ContextMenus`'s parent.  Are you saying that you want to modify this variable when hovering over certain table cells?  Because that can easily be done by passing props down.  Care to clarify?

Answer (score 1):

Please view the [Event System](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/events.html) for the React for the proper way of handling this.

It may be a little tricky from the way you have your components set up in your fiddle, but it is just like what you are doing with `onClick`.  I believe you want `onMouseOver` but it may require `onMouseEnter` and `onMouseOut`.

From your fiddle, you would attach this event listener to each of the `td` and have them listen for the hover, and set state based on that.  Then, you would have that state determine the `backgroundColor` for that individual table cell.

Because you want the `backgroundColor` to change per individual table cell, you cannot use the `contentMenuStyle` variable.  Instead make a style variable that each of the table cells can use.

Answer (score 0):

You can change style properties of an element like so:

```
document.getElementById('whatever-element').style.backgroundColor = '#somecolor'
```

With jQuery, just use a selector like this:

```
$('#whatever-element').css('background', '#somecolor');
```

If you want to be able to pass in an object of styles, like `var someStyle = { ... }`, just make the object with keys and values that correspond to, say, jQuery's `.css()` method:

```
var someStyle = {
    backgroundColor: 'lightblue',
    // etc.
};

$('.some-other-element').css(someStyle);
```

Check out the [jQuery docs on .css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/) for more info.